# horizontal center align nested ul li

Tags: jquery, css, html

Well I am just trying to design a navigation menu such that when I hover on the menu item it will fork a horizontal child list with sub menu, up till this everything is working properly. But now i want the child list should be aligned center with respect to its parent. 
this will look something like this drawn with equal-to(=) sign, Please help.

```
  =        =      =
= = =      =   = = = =
```

This is the HTML structure:

```
 <ul>  
     <li><a href="jjbrides.php" rel="pageUrl">collection</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="jjbrides.php" rel="pageUrl">JJ brides</a></li>
         <li><a href="maketime-stop.php" rel="pageUrl" class="subnav">make time stop</a></li>
         <li><a href="jjbrides.php" rel="pageUrl">JJ brides</a></li>
         <li><a href="maketime-stop.php" rel="pageUrl" class="subnav">make time stop</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="upcoming-event.php" rel="pageUrl">events</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="upcoming-event.php" rel="pageUrl">upcoming</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

/* css style */

```
.nav > li {
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav li a {
    color: #737663;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 42px;
    font-family:'sangbleu_bp_sanslight';
    text-transform:lowercase
}
.nav > li > a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size:20px;
}
.nav li.navhover > a {
    color: #737663!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav li a:active, .nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*.nav li > ul{margin-left: 20px;}*/
.nav li> ul li a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family:'FarnhamDisplay-LightItal'!important;
    font-size:18px;
}
.nav li ul li a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color:#737663;
    padding:10px 20px!important;
}
.nav li.navhover ul li:hover a {
    color: #737663;
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.nav li.navhover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.nav li ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin-top:3px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav li ul li:hover a, .inviewlink {
    border-bottom:3px solid #737663;
}
.inviewlink:hover {
    margin-bottom:-3px
}
.nav > li.active, .nav > li.active:hover {
    /*background-color: #eee;*/
}
.nav > li.active a {
    color:#737663
}
.nav > li.active:before {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:' ';
    visibility:visible;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
}
.nav > li.active > ul {
    display:block;
}
.nav > li:first-child + li {
    margin-right: 365px;
}
.nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.nav>li {
    z-index:1
}
.nav li.navhover {
    z-index:3
}
.nav li.navhover:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    width: 3000px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    /* top:0; */
    height: 45px;
    left: -1000px;
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe add a couple more line breaks to the css code. It's very hard to read it this way. If you are as lazy (and as smart ^^) as me, maybe consider using a site like [this](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) or some kind of plugin to do the job for you. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) is a good place to save some code if you feel it is too much to post here. If

Comment: Is there any live demo or a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Your DOM structure is incorrect, it doesn't have classes given in stylesheet. can you please fix it?

Comment: doubt it can be done without script. Count menu items and offset accordingly

Comment: The code you shared doesn't reproduce what you describe...

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you should check this link in this example sub menu comes in center and I hope it will helps you.

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.nav{
  display:block;
  list-style:none;
  text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
.nav li { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;  
  border: 1.5px solid #FFF;
}
.nav li a { 
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2000;    
  background-color: #999;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #999 ;
  color: #000;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    top: 30px;  
}

.nav li:hover > a {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#333;  
}

.nav li ul { 
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;  
  border: 1.5px solid #FFF;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
  left: -2px;
}

.nav li li:hover > a {
  color:#000;
  background-color:#999;  
}

.nav li li{ 
  position: relative;
  border: 1.5px solid #FFF;
  height: 25px;

}
.nav li li a {
  height: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2000;    
  background-color: #999;
}
li li.active {
  background-color: #a9d9d9 ;
  color: #007f7b;
}

.nav li li:hover ul {
  left: -2px;
    top: 25px; 
}

ul.nav li > ul {
  width: 700px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color:red;
}

ul.nav li > ul > li > ul {
  background-color:green;
  height: 25px; 
}

ul.nav li > ul > li { display: none; }
ul.nav li:hover li { display: block; }
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/h4noqwn7/)***

Comment: Thanks for help but this is not coming center as i want

Comment: Oh okay what you want now exactly.

Comment: as i explained with (equal to drawing)  the sub menu should be come center aligned    
  =       =       =
= = =     =    = = = =